# Compressing a bitmap using Encoder in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, compression

I am doing a WPF forms application for compress .bmp images in my project. 
I want to compress an image using RLE compression algorithm and Huffman.
 I tried below code by referring MSDN, but original image and compressed images have same sizes.

```
    private List<double> HuffmanAndRle(int size)
    {
        try
        {
            if((size > _image.Width) || (size > _image.Height))
                throw new Exception("size is too large");
            Bitmap bitmaporg = crop(size);
            Bitmap bitmapRLE = crop(size);
            Bitmap bitmapHuffman = crop(size);
            ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo ;

            myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/bmp");


            var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            var enc = new Encoder(Encoder.Compression.Guid);
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
            bitmapHuffman.Save("C:/Hffman.bmp", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
            //bitmapHuffman.Save()


            var myEncoderParameters1 = new EncoderParameters(1);
            myEncoderParameters1.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionNone);
            bitmaporg.Save("C:/org.bmp", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters1);



            var myEncoderParameters2 = new EncoderParameters(1);
            myEncoderParameters2.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionRle);
            bitmapRLE.Save("C:/RLE.bmp", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters2);


            var org =new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:/org.bmp"));
            var rle = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:/RLE.bmp"));
            var huffman = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:/Hffman.bmp"));

            var dobles = new List<double>();
            dobles.Add(ImageSize2(huffman)/ImageSize2(org));
            dobles.Add(ImageSize2(rle)/ImageSize2(org));
            return dobles;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

so where is the problem ??

Comment: I'm confused. Are you not, here, loading the (potentially compressed) bitmaps into bitmaps objects again, thus uncompressing the images in the process?

Answer (score 0):

Huffman algorithm is not good for compression for all files, if we have a small amount of characters our compress result will be better, but if we have more then compression will be less or in some cases more then original file size. The best compression we have when we used Huffman algorithm on text files.

Comment: That is not the exact answer of the question,that is a comment.